# multiple tasks with executor framework

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I was writing a program to implement for running two different tasks with Executor Framework as part to learn multi-threading. Earlier, I was using synchronized method to fullfill this requirement  but its giving wrong results. Then, I learned that using Executor Framework is better approach for thread management.

**Below Progam using synchronize methods**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.*;
class FileWriteThreadExample implements Runnable{
    /*This class needs to write some content into text file*/

    public synchronized void run() {
            StringBuilder thisProgamMessage = new StringBuilder();

            try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\TestNotes.txt", true);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw))
            {
                for(int i=1; i<=50;i++){
                    //Thread.sleep(500);
                    //System.out.println(i);

                    thisProgamMessage.append(i+":"+Math.random()+"\n");

                }
                out.println(thisProgamMessage.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
            }

    }
}

class FileWriteThreadExample2 implements Runnable{
    /*This class needs to write some content into text file*/

    public synchronized void run() {
            StringBuilder thisProgamMessage = new StringBuilder();
            try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\TestNotes.txt", true);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw))
            {


                System.out.println("Starting Second Write Thread Task");
                for(int i=50; i>=1;i--){
                    //Thread.sleep(500);
                    //System.out.println(i);
                    thisProgamMessage.append(i+"====>"+Math.random()+"\n");
                }
                out.println(thisProgamMessage.toString());
                System.out.println("Completing Second Write Thread Task");
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){
                fnfe.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IOException ioex) {
                ioex.printStackTrace();
            }
            /*catch(InterruptedException ie){
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }*/     
    }
}
class SynchronizeTest {
        public static void main (String[] args) {
            FileWriteThreadExample t1 = new FileWriteThreadExample();
            FileWriteThreadExample2 t2 = new FileWriteThreadExample2();

            t1.start();

            t2.start();

        }
    }
```

Problem here is I don't know to write code for Executor that execute two tasks. I had implemented code with ExecutorService for running single task i.e.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    public void doStuff() {


        es.submit(new MyRunnable());


    }
```

Finally, can someone suggest me to implement two different tasks with Executor Framework ?

PS: Let me know for any confusion on understanding problem statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
public void doStuff() {
    es.submit(new FirstTask());  // FirstTask implements Callable
    es.submit(new SecondTask());  // SecondTask implements Callable
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
public void doStuff() {
    Collection<Callable> tasks = Arrays.asList(new Callable[]
            { new FirstTask(), new SecondTask() });
    es.invokeAll(tasks);
}
```

Each task may synchronize with each other like normal, just as if you were running the tasks in raw threads yourself.

*Do note that `ExecutorService` requires the `Callable` interface rather than the `Runnable` interface.*

Comment: @Travis, invokeAll method receives only parameters of Callable type, I guess above code will throw compilation error.

Comment: @sabarinathanu Good catch. I have now corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your intent of exercise. in your synchronize  version. you synchronized nothing. the two threads access TestNotes.txt sequentially, because only one file can open a file for write at a moment.is this your intent?

Comment: my use case is two threads wants to write different text on single text file. Hence, need to use executor framework.